# IBM Integration Bus: How to read user defined node (Java) complex (table) property in Java extension code

Tags: messagebroker

I created Java user defined node in IntegrationToolkit (9.0.0.1) and assigned it with several properties. Two of the node properties are simple (of String type) and one property is complex (table property with predefined type of User-defined) that is consisted of another two simple properties.
By following the documentation I was able to read two simple properties in my Java extension class (that extends MbNode and implements MbNodeInterface) by making getters and setters that match the names of the two simple properties. Documentation also states that getters and setters should return and set String values whatever the real simple type of a property may be. Obviously, this would not work for my complex node property.
I was also able to read User Defined Properties that are defined on the message flow level, by using CMP (Integration Buss API) classes, which was another impossible thing to do from user defined node without CMP. At one point I began to think that my complex property would be among User Defined Properties, (although UDPs are defined on the flow level and my property is defined on the custom node level) based on some other random documentation and some other forum discussion.
I finally deduced that the complex property should map to MbTable type (as it is so stated in that type's description), but I was not able to use that.
Does anyone know how to access user defined node's complex(table) property value from Java?

Answer (score 0):

I recently started working with **WebSphere Message Broker v 8.0.0.5** for one of my projects and I was going to ask the same question until SO suggested your question which answered my question. It might be a little late for this question but it may help others having similar questions.

After many frustrating hours consulting IBM documentation this is what I found following your thread:

You're correct about the properties being available as user-defined properties (UDP) but only at the node level.

According to the [JavaDoc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.plugin.doc/com/ibm/broker/plugin/MbTable.html) for `MbTable` class (*emphasis added to call out the relevant parts*):

> MbTable is a complex data type which contains one or more rows of simple data types. It structure is very similar to a * standard java record set. It can not be constructed in a node but instead is returned by the **getUserDefinedAttribute()** on the **MbNode** class. Its primary use is in allowing **complex attributes to be defined on nodes** instead of the normal static simple types. It can only be used in the runtime if a version of the toolkit that supports complex properties is being used.

You have to call `com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.getUserDefinedAttribute` which will return an instance of `com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbTable`. However, the broker runtime doesn't call any setter methods for the complex attributes during the node initialization process like it does for simple properties. Also, you cannot access the complex attributes in either the constructor or the setter methods of other simple properties in the node class. These are available only in the `run` or `evaluate` method.

The following is the decompiled method definition of `com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.getUserDefinedAttribute`.

```
public Object getUserDefinedAttribute(String string) {
    Object object;
    String string2 = "addDynamicTerminals";
    if (Trace.isOn) {
        Trace.logNamedEntry((Object)this, (String)string2);
    }
    if ((object = this.getUDA(string)) != null && object.getClass() == MbElement.class) {
        try {
            MbTable mbTable;
            MbElement mbElement = (MbElement)object;
            object = mbTable = new MbTable(mbElement);
        }
        catch (MbException var4_5) {
            if (Trace.isOn) {
                Trace.logStackTrace((Object)this, (String)string2, (Throwable)var4_5);
            }
            object = null;
        }
    }
    if (Trace.isOn) {
        Trace.logNamedExit((Object)this, (String)string2);
    }
    return object;
}
```

As you can see it always returns an instance of `MbTable` if the attribute is found.

I was able to access the complex attributes with the following code in my node definition:

```
@Override
public void evaluate(MbMessageAssembly inAssembly, MbInputTerminal inTerminal) throws MbException {
    checkUserDefinedProperties();
}

/**
 * @throws MbException
 */
private void checkUserDefinedProperties() throws MbException {
    Object obj = getUserDefinedAttribute("geoLocations");
    if (obj instanceof MbTable) {
        MbTable table = (MbTable) obj;
        int size = table.size();
        int i = 0;
        table.moveToRow(i);
        for (; i < size; i++, table.next()) {
            String latitude = (String) table.getValue("latitube");
            String longitude = (String) table.getValue("longitude");
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/as09970_.htm?lang=en-us#as09970_7) for declaring attributes for user-defined extensions in Java is surprisingly silent on this little bit of detail.

*Please note that all the references and code are for **WebSphere Message Broker v 8.0.0** and should be relevant for **IBM Integration Bus 9.0.0.1** too.*